# Is it possible to crop an Element using Elm's std library? If not, is there a 3rd party lib for this?

Tags: forms, scroll, element, crop, elm

I often run across a situation where I've constructed an `Element` or `Form` and wish to crop the view down to a given area (i.e. for scrolling within a smaller rectangle) though I haven't been able to find any methods for this within their respective modules.

Is it possible to do this using Elm's std library? If not, are there any 3rd-party libraries capable of doing this?

Otherwise, perhaps there is a better way of achieving this?

Any help or suggestions appreciated!

Comment: So you want a small box with scrollbars with content in it that could be larger than the box?

Comment: @Apanatshka yes, this would be one example of where it would be useful. Another use-case example might be creating a movable 2D "camera" style view of a small area of the larger content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No scollbars (using the std library)

I can't find a way to crop but have scrollbars with the [current `Graphics.Element`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.0.1/Graphics-Element). What *is* possible is to crop without having scrollbars, either through a `container` that's smaller than it's contents or by resizing an element with `size`. I think the container way is more robust, as resizing an image will actually warp the image.
Here's an example:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)
import Text

string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est."

main : Element
main =
  let element =
    leftAligned (Text.fromString string)
    |> container 400 300 topLeft
  in container 205 200 topLeft element
```

## Scrollbars (via "3rd party" library)

If you want scrollbars, you'll probably need at least a little bit of html from [`elm-html`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/latest). Note that the author of the library is also the author of Elm, so it's not quite 3rd party :P . You can keep it minimal by using [conversions](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/3.0.0/Html#Conversions) to html and from html and wrapping it in a `div` with style attributes that define the smaller size and the right overflow property. As long as that div has a known size, it should be easy to convert back to an `Element`.